# How to identify missing number sequence of Ms Excel and to insert a required row with user defined values

Tags: c#, sql, excel, matlab

I need to identify missing number sequence from column A of Ms Excel and have to insert a missed sequence in between with duplicate value using C# code / Matlab code.

Here is that sample figure of missing sequence.

[image]

In above figure, "201208A and 201209A" of column A is missing. So, i have to identify that and insert a required missed sequence data(201208A, 201209A) with value as 0(zero) in corresponding row of column B.

Like this,

[image]

Seeking for some valuable suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? In Matlab look at `xlsread` and `xlswrite` for example, in C# try out the office interop

Comment: As Dan has mentioned, please give some indication of where exactly you are stuck. Is it the interfacing with Excel, is it the algorithm to find missing elements...?

Answer (score 1):

A Matlab version could look like this:

```
%// read data from excel document
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('test.xlsx');
c1 = raw(:,1); %// 1st column
c2 = raw(:,2); %// 2nd column
%// remove letter 'A' from the end of each string of 1st column and convert to numerical array 
D = cellfun(@(x)str2double(x(1:end-1)), c1);
%// indices of "holes"
iHoles = find(diff(D)>1);
%// fill the holes from the end, since arrays D and c2 are growing
for n=length(iHoles):-1:1,
    d1 = D(iHoles(n))+1;
    d2 = D(iHoles(n)+1)-1;
    d = (d1:d2).'; %//'
    D = [D(1:iHoles(n)); d; D(iHoles(n)+1:end)];
    c2 = [c2(1:iHoles(n)); num2cell(zeros(length(d),1)); c2(iHoles(n)+1:end)];
end
%// convert numerical array back to cell array adding letter 'A'
c1 = arrayfun(@(x){[num2str(x) 'A']}, D);
%// combine results and write to excel file
data = [c1 c2];
xlswrite('result.xlsx',data);
```

Hope it will work for you.